# find a document with the current username in a helper

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a helper like this:

```js
this.helpers({
  data() {
    return Customers.findOne({ user: Meteor.user().username });
  }
});
```

but an error occurs, It seems that the user is logging in when the helper is executing, How can I execute the helper after the user is logged in ?

Comment: I hope that someone has other solutions better than the one that I proposed, so please feel free to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if is the best solution but I created a deferred promise that wait for the user to login and resolve the $state.

```
resolve: {
  currentUser: ($q) => {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Meteor.autorun(function() {
      if(!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        if(!Meteor.user()) {
          deferred.reject('PERMISSION_REQUIRED');
        } else {
          deferred.resolve();
        }
      }
    });
```

I hope that it can be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data() {
    if(Meteor.user()){
        return Customers.findOne({ user: Meteor.user().username });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try builtin `currentUser` users helper, which check whether the user is logged in. Like that:

```html
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{data}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Is this Blaze ? I'm using the Angular implementation of Meteor

Comment: @2JN ugh, yes, it's Blaze :) But it simple calls `Meteor.user()`, which is available in Angluar also, I think.

Comment: It is, is just not available in boot time, but thanks, I will try blaze once I end this project.